# Convert 16 bit PCM data into numpy array of amplitudes

Tags: python, numpy, audio

I may not be using the right terminology here. I have a numpy array like:

> array([ 82,  73,  70, ...,   1, 230,   1], dtype=uint8)

It's supposedly in 16 bit PCM format.

I need to turn this into a numpy audio waveform. And in case that's not the right terminology, I'll explain really well what that is: literally the sound wave amplitudes at some sample rate.

I also need do it as fast as possible with Python.

Answer (score 1):

That is indeed, literally the sound wave amplitudes at some sample rate. But stored in a `np.uint8` dtype. For example, if you want to hear it in a Jupyter Notebook, you can try:

```py
import numpy as np
s = np.array([ 82, 73, 70, 2, 1, 230, 1], dtype=np.uint8)

from IPython.display import Audio
Audio(s, rate=22050)
```

then you can hear your sound.

[image: jupyter notebook screenshot]

Comment: I just installed jupyter from a dir with above python code and it launched a browser showing same as your above ... now how to I execute the python code from inside jupyter so it renders the audio play widget as shown in your above ?  Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, to be honest, I don't know. According to docs, you can't. https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html May be you can ask another SO question.

Comment: @armamut how to convert this array into woords?

Answer (score 0):

Reshape your array of n samples to new shape(n/2, 2)
Multiply second column by 256 (most significant byte)
Sum pairs into 16 bit value

```py
a = np.array([ 0x82, 0x73, 0x70, 0x1, 0x30, 0x1], dtype=np.uint8)
b = a.reshape(-1,2)*np.array([1,256], np.uint16)
c = b.sum(axis=1)

print(hex(c[0])) # '0x7382'
print(hex(c[1])) # '0x170'
print(hex(c[2])) # '0x130'
```